# Hadoop MapReduce Input key error

Tags: hadoop

I want to pass an array of float to be the key in mapper,

```
Such as [0.6, 0, 10]
```

I transform it to string by using StringUtils.join, and write

```
context.write(new Text(str), value);
```

But in the reducer class, I found what I got is:

```
"0 0 1"
```

How to fix it? I am using hadoop 1.0.4

Comment: what separator did you give while using `StringUtils.join` ?

Comment: Can you upload your snippet for `StringUtils.join`?

Answer (score 0):

You can emit float array using `ArrayWritable`.I am not sure in emitting array as key,below is how you emit the same as value.

```
ArrayWritable does not implement WritableComparable, so it can't currently
be used as a mapper output key - those keys have to be sorted during the
shuffle, and thus the type must be WritableComparable.
```

Normally for emitting keys we use custom Writable Comparable Class.

For that you should define the same in driver class
public class Driver {

```
public static class DoubleArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public DoubleArrayWritable() {
        super(DoubleWritable.class);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

In Mapper

```
DoubleArrayWritable pointArray = new DoubleArrayWritable();
DoubleWritable[] data = new DoubleWritable[numAttributes];
for (int k = 0; k < numAttributes; k++) {
    data[k] = new DoubleWritable(point[k]);
}
pointArray.set(data);
context.write(new Text("Array"), pointArray);
```

Hope this helps in some point.